# Синтаксическая ошибка: unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

Tags: php

При загрузке страницы выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING.

Вот строчка кода, в которой возникает ошибка:

```
    if($myrow['Loginid']==$Id)echo"<div> <?switch($_SESSION['id'])
{ 
    case 2: 
        echo users1(); break;
    case 1: echo users2(); break;
    case 3: echo moderator(); break;
    case 4: echo admin(); break;
    default: 
}; ?></div>"?>
```

Comment: двойная кавычка не закрыта

Comment: Это полный код и тут двойная кавычка закрыта.

Comment: точку с запятой попробуйте поставить

Comment: Возможно, стоит сделать `({$_SESSION['id']})` или же `(" . $_SESSION['id'] . ")`.

Comment: где именно точку с запятой?

Comment: Regent, ваш вариант помог спасибо.

Comment: @Максим110700 на здоровье. Раз вопрос решён, можно либо удалить  вопрос, либо я могу это разместить в  качестве ответа, если вы готовы отметить его как правильный.

Comment: Хорошо отметьте как правильный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В строках не может быть кода на PHP. Определитесь: или вы внутри `<? ?>` используете любой код и выводите текст с помощью echo и конкатенации, или внутри `<?= ?>` вычисляете строку. Внутри строки ни `<? ?>`, ни `<?= ?>` использоваться не могут, потому что вы уже выполняете код на PHP. Используйте в этом случае конкатенацию.

Если заблудились в скобках, то у PHP есть альтернативный синтаксис для шаблонов с помесью кода и голого HTML, который удобен при написании view.

Например:

```
<? if ($condition): ?>
     <div>
<?     switch ($value): ?>
<?       case 1: echo foo(); break; ?>
<?       case 2: echo bar(); break; ?>
<?       case 3: echo baz(); break; ?>
<?     endswitch ?>
     </div>
<? endif ?>
```

Или в традиционном синтаксисе:

```
<? if ($condition) { ?>
     <div>
<?     switch ($value) {
         case 1: echo foo(); break;
         case 2: echo bar(); break;
         case 3: echo baz(); break;
       } ?>
     </div>
<? } ?>
```

Или так:

```
<? if ($condition): ?>
     <div>
<?     switch ($value): ?>
<?       case 1: ?>
           <?= foo(); ?>
<?         break; ?>
<?       case 2: ?>
           <?= bar(); ?>
<?         break; ?>
<?       case 3: ?>
           <?= baz(); ?>
<?         break; ?>
<?     endswitch ?>
     </div>
<? endif ?>
```